# Page with image flickers when video is playing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

While recreating my app's UI, I added an extra grid with an image to the page. Unfortunately, the page flickers unbearably every time a video plays. When removing that image, the flickering is gone. I've tried using a `BitmapCache` on many elements in the page, but the flickering persists. Any ideas on why this is happening?

The screenshot below shows the amount of elements the pivot item has:
[image]

XAML: http://pastebin.com/Z4JF0sfj

Just some extra information: I'm testing the app on the WP 8.1 Preview. I don't have access WP 8, so I don't know if this also occurs there.

Update: I've found out that the page doesn't flicker at all when the video is playing in fullscreen mode.

Comment: (Does the entire page flicker, or just the image?)

Comment: @user2864740, the entire page flickers

Answer (score 0):

I think the page flickers because your browser hasn't enough grafic memory. When you play the video full screen it only has to render 1 video -> easier than a video in a page.
I hope this helps.